# Neglect all pages/resources in @requestmapping except specific extension

Tags: spring-security

I am building an app which is having combination of jsp, HTML, css pages. I want to call a method controller using @RequestMapping but only for HTML pages(all the pages having extension: .html).

For example below controller works fine for all index.html/index.jsp pages.

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/index*" })
public String index(Model model) {
    // do something
}
```